# Show hide fields in Jasper Report on the Fly at runtime

Tags: oracle, jsf, jasper-reports

I have a search page in an application developed using *JSF* / *Oracle 11g* / *iReport 4.1*.

Users select fields and records of employees are returned based on selected fields in a list further displayed in a data table on jsf page and finally user clicks on print and prints the listed records using jasper reports. This is happening all fine. Now I want to ask, if user select certain check boxes against the search values and wants the JasperReports to show only those selected fields..then

- is that possible in JasperReports?
- if yes...just a slight hint how to go about that?

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can do it with help of [***JasperReports API***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) or [***DynamicJasper API***](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref/).

You can find a lot of samples for ***DynamicJasper API*** using [this link](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/).

And you can also look at [this sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/noxmldesign/index.html#noxmldesign) for ***JasperReports API***